# Retrieving user's Info from firebase based on project name and Details-Swift Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase, data-retrieval

Here's the dashboard structure with some of the users for an iOS application using swift and firebase:

```
{
"users" : {
"0a0462bb-86a1-4140-bda2-90a62236ab1e" : {
  "Picker" : "Jeddah",
  "details" : "I'm here",
  "email" : "y@gmail.com",
  "name" : "y",
},
"0b71693a-4f16-4759-acd6-706da1a466a0" : {
  "Picker" : "Jubail",
  "details" : "iOS second",
  "email" : "Siham0@gmail.com",
  "name" : "Siham",
},
"0b71693a-4f16-4759-acd6-706da1a466a0" : {
  "Picker" : "Jeddah",
  "details" : "",
  "email" : "roro0@gmail.com",
  "name" : "roro",
}
 }
}
```

As in the picture bellow:

[image]

The table view in the simulator contains the name and the details for all of the users whose picker is Jeddah.

What I want now is to retrieve the name, email and details in labels in another view controller whenever the user clicks at any cell!

For example, If I clicked on the first cell, the second view controller will have the following:

Name:
y

Details:I'm here

Email:
y@gmail.com

What should I do to make that work? And
What's the structure of retrieving function should I use?

Comment: Why no one has answered the question? :(

Comment: The question is unclear. Your first screen shot shows y was tapped but the data in the detail view doesn't match. Just like the data in your last screen shot: the email in your dataset is n@g.com, but the screen shot is showing y@g.com. Is there a correlation? Also, you mention you query for  Picker is Jeddah, however, that code is not included. Finally, the observe event that's posted will load everything in the users node, iterate over all of the children replacing the .text values in your view in rapid succession. If you can clarify the question and clean it up, we can help.

Comment: Execuse my english, cause it's not my native language.

Comment: I edited the question and tried to clarify it as can as I can. I hope you get what I want now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did make a array of all listing value by easy format and display list of item like following:

```
var namesArray : NSMutableArray = []
```

And it's `viewDidLaod` Method look like following:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        ref.queryOrderedByChild("Picker").queryEqualToValue("Makkah")
                    .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in


                        if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSMutableDictionary{
                            print("print \(dict)")


                            for (key,value) in dict {
                                 let mainDict = NSMutableDictionary()
                                mainDict.setObject(key, forKey: "userid")


                                 if let dictnew = value as? NSMutableDictionary{

                                    if let metname = dictnew["name"] as? String
                                    {
                                        mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "name")

                                    }
                                    if let metname = dictnew["Picker"] as? String
                                    {
                                        mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "Picker")

                                    }
                                    if let metname = dictnew["details"] as? String
                                    {
                                        mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "details")

                                    }
                                    if let metname = dictnew["email"] as? String
                                    {
                                        mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "email")

                                    }
                                    if let metname = dictnew["provider"] as? String
                                    {
                                        mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "provider")

                                    }

                                }
                                self.namesArray.addObject(mainDict)
                        }

                            print("arrayt is \(self.namesArray)")


                    }

                        self.CookingTableView.reloadData()
                        })


    }
```

And its array Show in TableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` must be have following code:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.CookingTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CookingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CookingTableViewCell

        if let name = namesArray[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{

             cell.BusinessNameLabel?.text = name["name"] as? String
            cell.DescriptionLabel?.text = name["details"] as? String
        }

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

        return cell

    }
```

Now the listing thing is complete. Let display its details on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


                 tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in

                    let DetailsViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProjectDetailsViewController") as! ProjectDetailsViewController

                    if let name = self.namesArray[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{

                        DetailsViewController.self.strUserid = name["userid"] as? String
                    }


                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailsViewController, animated: true)

        }
    }
```

Here above didSelect method i Pass the `userID` that unique user id need to get it's details in PushedViewController. You can also send selected items's wall dictionary to nextviewController but i do with called firebase query method  in nextViewController so the nextViewController code look like:

```
var strUserid : NSString!
```

And it's ViewDidLoad:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("idis \(self.strUserid)")


      ref.childByAppendingPath(self.strUserid as String).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in


         if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSMutableDictionary{

            print("dict is \(dict)")

            if let name = dict["name"] as? String
            {
               self.Name.text = name

            }

            if let details = dict["details"] as? String
            {
                self.Details.text = details

            }

            if let email = dict["email"] as? String
            {
                self.Email.text = email

            }

        }



            })
    }
```

That's It Hope your issue going to be solve. I did this type of approach with above way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `tableView` showing some data from Firebase, I'm assuming you're already making a successful call to your Firebase and getting the data.

The best way to do this would be for you to write a custom class `User` or something appropriately named where you can store all the details in the initial call to Firebase.

Then, in your `tableView` you can just show the data you want there, and when a cell is tapped, you send that instance of your `User` class to the next `ViewController` via the `prepareForSegue` method.

In the next `ViewController` you now have access to all the data of that `User` so you can display whatever you need/want to show on that page.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

The `User` class or whatever you choose to call it will be a separate Swift file. [Here's an example](https://github.com/nishantroy/Buzz-Movie-iOS/blob/master/Buzz%20Movie%20iOS/Movie.swift) of a `Movie` class I wrote to keep track of movie data.

You can have an array of your class: `var movieArray = [Movie]()`

Then you can go through all your Firebase data, create new instances of your class and append to your array.

```
func loadMovies() {
        print("Loading movies now")
        currentUserMovies.observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) in
            let json = JSON(snapshot.value)
            var movieArr = [Movie]()
            print(json)
            for (key, subJson) in json {
                let name = key
                let userrating = subJson["User Rating"].int!
                let imagePath = subJson["Image"].string!
                let plot = subJson["Plot"].string! ?? "No Plot Found!"
                let imdbRating = subJson["IMDB Rating"].string!
                var image = UIImage()
                if let url = NSURL(string: imagePath) {
                    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                        image = UIImage(data: data)!
                    }
                }
                let movie = Movie(name: name, rating: userrating, image: image, plot: plot, imdbRating: imdbRating)
                movieArr.append(movie!)
            }
            self.myArray = movieArr
        }
    }
```

I am using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) here to parse the data. You can find examples of how to do that on their Github.

You would have your `prepareForSegue` method in the TableViewController.
EXAMPLE:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        print("Preparing")
        if (segue.identifier == "showSearchResult")
        {
            if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DisplayMovieViewController {
                destinationViewController.plot = self.moviePlot
                destinationViewController.imdbRating = self.movieRating
                destinationViewController.name = self.movieName
                destinationViewController.imagePath = self.moviePicturePath

            }
        }

    }
```

I have the properties `plot, imagePath, name and imdbRating` declared in my `DisplayMovieViewController`. The `prepareForSegue()` method sets these values before the segue happens.

[Here is my project](https://github.com/nishantroy/Buzz-Movie-iOS/tree/master/Buzz%20Movie%20iOS) if you need more examples/sample code to look at. Download it and run it if you would like.

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it out now and see if it helps.